# CSS reverse div flow

Tags: html, css

[image]

This works for the example on the left.

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  Message 1
</div>
<div class="alert">
  Message 2
</div>
<div class="alert">
  Message 3
</div>
```

How do I make the right example work? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're going to want to have the alerts appear in front of the main view, you should use absolute positioning:

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.main-view {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue, white);
  
  /* Ensures .alert-container is positioned relative to the main view and not higher up the element tree. */
  position: relative; 
}

.alert-container {
  /* Absolutely position the alert container */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Position the container 30px from the bottom */
  bottom: 30px;
  
  /* Position the container 30px from the right */
  right: 30px;
  
  /* Ensures the alert container stays in front of the main view */
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-view">
  <div class="alert-container">
    <div class="alert">
      Message 1
    </div>
    <div class="alert">
      Message 2
    </div>
    <div class="alert">
      Message 3
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```